# Python splitting text into two lines instead of printing one

Tags: python, deserialization, pyserial

I'm reading sensor data with a RedBoard QWIIC. The program outputs data which looks like this:

```
408 10  45.47   98760.30    23.33   413   19.17
    
400 7   45.45   98758.38    23.33   414   19.17
    
415 16  45.45   98757.56    23.33   414   19.17
    
405 3   45.45   98758.38    23.33   414   19.17
```

Yet when I run my Python program, the .txt file looks like *this:*

```
07/21/2022 14:12:49 400 0   45.42   98763.58    23.34   406
    19.17
    
07/21/2022 14:12:52 400 0   45.45   98759.20    23.34   406
    19.18
    
07/21/2022 14:12:55 400 0   45.48   98764.69    23.34   405
    19.18
```

The Python program in question:

```
import serial
import time


serialPort_1 = 'COM3'
baud_rate = 9600
write_to_file_path = "test 1 7-21-22.txt"

output_file = open(write_to_file_path, "w+")
ser1 = serial.Serial(serialPort_1, baud_rate, timeout=4)

while 1:
    line1 = ser1.readline()

    line1 = line1.decode("utf-8")  
    print(time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") + ' ' + line1)
    output_file.write(time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")+' '+line1)


    time.sleep(0.00001)
```

How do I get the program to stop indenting between these last two values? I have already tried changing from printing a "\t" character after the sensor outputs to printing a few spaces instead.

Comment: Nothing here is going to do that.  How are you looking at the file?  Have you done a hexdump to see what it really looks like?  My guess is the file is just fine.  If you're on a primitive system, perhaps your terminal line length is set to 80, so the tty package is helpfully breaking the line.   By the way, your time.sleep is silly.  The minimum sleep value is about 0.015, depending on the operating system.  The scheduler doesn't run any more often than that.  Since `readline` blocks (with a timeout), there's no need to sleep at all.

Comment: I'm opening the .txt file directly. I don't know how to do a hexdump. I did try looking at the character length of each line and the maximum length is 51 characters.

Comment: "opening the .txt file directly" -- in what?  Using `cat` or using an editor?  If you're on Linux, do `hexdump -C xxx.txt`.

Comment: I'm on Windows, and I'm just clicking the .txt file and it opens in Notepad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution. It all lies in the newline delimiter passed to the read_until() command. For the input line, I use:

```
RedBoardline = RedBoardSerial.read_until()
RedBoardline = RedBoardline.rstrip()
```

This eliminated the 0x0A (a.k.a. ASCII code 10 or "\n") character at the end of the line. Hope this helps someone.